# Se registran las horas con una hora menos. ¿Se debe ajustar phpMyAdmin o corregir la función DATE()?

Tags: php, mysql

cada fila que se inserta tiene una columna que indica la fecha y hora en que se registra el usuario. Pero, se registran las horas con una hora menos. ¿Se debe ajustar phpMyAdmin o corregir la función DATE()?

La función que utilizo es:

```
$fecha_hora_actual = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes cambiar la zona horaria en `php.ini` o en código:

**php.ini**:

```
date.timezone = "Europe/Madrid"
```

**PHP** (al comienzo de tu código / config.file):

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid");
```